# Forma correcta de escribir una pregunta de la que sospechas la respuesta

Tags: gramática

### Spanish

En una pregunta donde inquirimos sobre algo de lo que sospechamos saber la respuesta, cual sería la forma correcta de colocar el signo de interrogación final:

> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿es este el tuyo: xxxxx?

O:

> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿es este el tuyo? xxxxx

Me inclino más por la primera opción, pero no consigo encontrar la respuesta correcta.

---

### English

In a question where we suspect to know the answer, where do I have to put the closing question mark:

> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿es este el tuyo: xxxxx?

Or:

> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿es este el tuyo? xxxxx

I think the first one is better, but I can't find the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En cualquier caso, el número forma parte de la pregunta, y se le daría una cierta entonación interrogativa a los números, a no ser que la pregunta sea retórica y el número es una auto respuesta, Así que podría ser:

> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿este es el tuyo: xxxxx?
>
> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿es el tuyo este: xxxxx?
>
> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿el tuyo es el xxxxx?
>
> Necesitaré un número de teléfono, ¿el xxxxx es el tuyo?

A diferencia de la forma interrogativa del inglés ("Is this ..?") en español hay bastante libertad en la colocación del sujeto. La construcción puede ser la misma que una frase afirmativa, con el sujeto delante ("¿este es ...?" o totalmente pospuesto ("es ... este?"), aunque eso no significa que  "¿es este ... ?" sea incorrecto.

Comment: +1: Solo para decir que "Es el tuyo este: xxx" no suena muy idiomático, aunque sea correcto. ¡No lo recomiendo!

Answer (score 4):

Varias opciones:

> Necesitaré un número de teléfono. El tuyo es xxxx, yyyy

Donde yyyy puede ser reemplazado por ejemplo por:

1. ¿no?
2. ¿no es cierto?
3. ¿verdad?
4. ¿no es verdad?
5. ¿es así?

Comment: Pero entonces ya cambia la forma original de la pregunta.

Comment: Efectivamente no creo que esta respuesta de solución a la pregunta original. Más bien mornaner quiere saber el lugar correcto donde se ubicaría el signo de interrogación, antes o después de, en este caso, el número de teléfono.

Comment: @JoulSauron Ninguna de las opciones expuestas en la pregunta aparece coloquialmente en las variantes del español que he escuchado. Es por ello que modifiqué la frase. La he editado luego de tu comentario para que sea mas parecida a la original

Comment: @belisarius Pues al menos creo que en España es una forma muy común de preguntar si algo es de alguien: _¿son estas tus llaves?_ o _¿estas llaves son tuyas?_ Además, en la forma en la que haces tú la pregunta tienes bastante certeza de la respuesta, pero en el original puede haber duda. De todas formas, es posible que varíe de un sitio a otro como comentas.

Comment: @JoulSauron Curiosamente _¿estas llaves son tuyas?_, es habitual en latinoamérica, pero (en mi opinión) no así para un número de teléfono

Comment: Me parece que lo que es poco coloquial es que se cambia el orden en que se coloca el verbo, como en inglés (This is yours / Is this yours?). Esto, si bien no es incorrecto, no suena natural en castellano. Pero a "¿Este es el tuyo?" no le veo nada raro. No estoy seguro de dónde habría que poner los signos de pregunta en el original, pero salvo por el orden del verbo en la segunda parte (y por el futuro simple), me parece perfectamente coloquial.

Comment: @JoulSauron Eso es, la pregunta viene de ahí. Cuando tienes unas llaves en la mano y estás frente a tu interlocutor es fácil preguntar _¿Estas llaves son tuyas?_ porque es obvio que te refieres a las que tienes en la mano. Lo mismo sucedería si tienes el número de telefono apuntado en un papel. Mi pregunta venía por la forma de trasladar eso a un texto escrito, por ejemplo un email. Sobre lo que dice Juan: El orden de la pregunta se podría cambiar, mi duda sirve igual para _..., ¿Este es el tuyo?_ porque como dice Sergio lo que pretendía saber es el lugar correcto del signo de interrogación.

Comment: @belisarius Como digo en mi anterior comentario, teniendo el número de teléfono apuntado en un papel sí sería una forma común de expresarlo. Ya conocía la forma de tu respuesta, pero lo que busco es saber cual es la forma correcta expresándolo como en mi pregunta, precisamente por no ser una forma tan común, por lo menos por escrito.

Comment: @mornaner Lo siento, la forma que estás tratando de utilizar no la he escuchado ni leído nunca refiriéndose a un número (teléfono, dirección, etc). Sí se utiliza con coloquialmente con _objetos_.